Is it possible to normalize FIR filter coefficients to "perserve gain on average"?
Let's say we are given a random discrete time FIR filter.
I'm wondering if there is a standard way to normalize its filter coefficient in a way to make the filter "energy preserving on average".
To clarify what I mean by that: As discussed in this question, only all-pass filters ($|H(f)| = 1$) are truly energy preserving. For an arbitrary filter, the gain is frequency dependent, and therefore any signal of a particular frequency will either be strengthened or attenuated, i.e., the energy of these particular signals obviously isn't energy preserved.
However, this made me wonder if it is possible to normalize the filter coefficients in a way that the gain is 1 when averaging over all possible frequencies?

As far as I can see, the common normalization of enforcing the filter coefficients to sum to 1 doesn't have this property, because it rather normalizes the gain at DC to be 1 (see e.g. this answer).


I'm wondering if there is a standard way to normalize its filter coefficient in a way to make the filter "energy preserving on average".

If the filter isn't all-pass, then there wouldn't be a way to do this without assuming an input spectrum.
You could easily normalize a filter such that when presented with white noise of a certain power, the filter output has that same power: just normalize the filter such that the sum (or integral, for a continuous-time filter) of the square of the impulse response equals 1.  I.e.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(\tau)^2 d\tau = 1 \tag 1$$
or
$$\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} h(n)^2 = 1 \tag 2$$
But that only normalizes the power for white noise.  Put in narrow-band noise that's in the band that the filter passes, and it'll be amplified.  Put in noise with content outside of the filter's passband and it'll be attenuated.

[...] there wouldn't be a way to do this without assuming an input spectrum. Indeed, by "averaging" I implicitly meant uniformly weighted over the entire spectrum, i.e., a uniform spectrum or white noise. Thanks!

@bluenote10: you need to be careful here with your assumptions. There are many classes of signal where the assumption of "white" is just plain wrong. Audio, for example, is mostly pink.
